# iOS Popup banner animation not working

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, popup, translation

I'm trying to create a popup banner (basically a wide custom view poping and hiding over the screen) with a translation animation. Here is the code I have so far:

```
- (void)popAddProductBanner {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:3]];
    [_addProductBanner setHidden:YES];
    UIView *bannerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HouraAddProductBannerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [_addProductBanner addSubview:bannerView];
    [UIView transitionWithView:_addProductBanner duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations: ^{
        [_addProductBanner setHidden:NO];
        [_addProductBanner setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -44.0)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(dismissAddProductBanner)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
    }];
}

-(void)dismissAddProductBanner {
    [UIView transitionWithView:_addProductBanner duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations: ^{
        [_addProductBanner setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 44.0)];
        [_addProductBanner setHidden:YES];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

This popup can be triggered all the way through the application via different buttons. My problem is that the poping animation works just fine but the hiding animation (which is the same but in the other way) doesn't work. The banner just disappear without any animation.

Does someone has any clue about what's going on here ? It would be really helpful to me. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't animate the hidden property. Instead animate the alpha property, and if you want set the hidden in the completion.
It currently works for the first animation because hidden is partially binded to alpha.

Comment: Thx, it made it. I put "setHidden" in the completion part and left only the translation in the animation. It works fine now.